# How can I use LibC/WINAPI to use a dvd as a binary blob?

Tags: c, winapi, libc

I was thinking recently, whenever I use a disc, I use it by either burning an image onto it, or by formatting it and using it like a USB. I never used it as a raw storage medium to poke bytes into/read bytes from.

I am now curious if it is possible to use a DVD as a blob of binary data that I can write bits onto as I please.

From what I understand, it is trivial to write to a DVD using C if I format it, so that I can interface it much like a typical C or D drive(I can even rename the disk name to C or D if I want to).

I'm curious if I can do the same without formatting the disk, so that the only bits on it are the ones that I write to, or the default ones.

To summarize, I want to be able to perform the following operations on an unformatted DVD-RW

1. read a bunch of bytes at an offset into an in-memory byte pool
2. overwrite a bunch of bytes at an offset from a in-memory byte pool without affecting other bytes on the disk

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: In short, you want to perform I/O on a raw dvd device.  Your ability to do something like this depends on the capabilities exposed to you by the kernel.  I am uncertain whether the Windows API exposes such a capability to anyone, but even if it did, you would probably find it unsatisfactory for most purposes.

Comment: im looking at [Image Mastering API atm(IMAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366450(v=vs.85).aspx), I am not sure why it would be unsatisfactory. I understand it might be slow but I imagine at worst, it should be at least possible to read whole dvd into memory, overwrite a byte of it, and write that blob back onto the disk much like burning a boot disk. I am willing to use COM/.NET to accomplish this if necessary(since they're binary compatible to C and are accessible via WINAPI).

Comment: It is certainly possible to read in a whole DVD image to a file (or memory, if you have enough), and / or to write a whole DVD image back out to the DVD device.  There is plenty of software and tools available that do this, including the IMAPI.  But DVDs don't make good random-access storage devices, and that's what you seemed to be saying you wanted to use them for.  You likely *can* do it, but an altogether different approach will likely serve better.  Again, for *most* purposes.

Comment: I know it will be fairly slow because of seek/moving parts but I was curious if it was possible to read/write at an offset. I know it is likely going to be slower than an HDD, and needs to be clustered for any sort of reliability, but I am only interested in the proof of concept, and whether it is possible without resorting to wrapping existing COM/.NET solutions(although I can't find any solutions that write at an offset).

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, you can just open the block device and do sufficiently aligned writes:

- [`Documentation/cdrom/packet-writing.txt` in the kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/cdrom/packet-writing.txt)

You only need to format the media as DVD+RW once, using `dvd+rw-format`.  This is a relatively simple procedure, so you could extract it from the source code of that tool.

However, according to the kernel documentation, what is a “sufficiently aligned write” is somewhat up to interpretation—the spec says 2 KiB, but some drives require more alignment.  There is also no wear leveling or sector remapping at this layer, so good results really require that you use on-disk data structures which reflect that this technology is closer in reality to write-once rather than truly random access.